# Помогите решить проблему с приемом функции на index страничке

Tags: php, mysql

Ребят почему когда пишу передать функцию, в данный момент `get_epson($connection);`
У меня на той странице где он должен появиться, страничка просто становиться белой. Вот полный код:

```
<?php 
    **$connection** = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'a0106522', '4101994fucking123', 'a0106522_Epson');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo 'ПРИВЕТ ('.mysqli_connect_errno().'): '. mysqli_connect_error();
        }

<?php 

    function **get_epson($connetion)** {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM epson";

        $result = musqli_query($connection, $sql);

        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($result);    
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    **get_epson($connection);**

?>
```

Comment: $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'a0106522', '4101994fucking123', 'a0106522_Epson');
        if(mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
            echo 'ПРИВЕТ ('.mysqli_connect_errno().'): '. mysqli_connect_error();

Comment: function get_epson($connetion) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM epson";
        
        $result = musqli_query($connection, $sql);
        
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($result);    
        echo '</pre>';
    }
    
    get_epson($connection);
    
    if(isset($connection)) {
        echo 'Привет';
    } else {
        echo 'Ничего нет';
    }

Comment: Под вопросом есть ссылка "править", все дополнения пишите в тексте вопроса. И делайте перед кодом отступ 4 пробела - тогда он оформляется как код (можно выделить код и нажать вверху редактора спец. кнопку `{}` для правильного оформления)

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, у вас в коде какая-то ошибка, но она не выводится. Вам нужно включить лог ошибок, иначе исправить ошибки будет очень сложно.
Сделать это можно разными способами:

1) **Рекомендую:** Включение вывода всех ошибок и предупреждений в файле `.htaccess`

```
php_value display_errors 1
php_value display_startup_errors 1
php_value error_reporting E_ALL
```

Эти строчки добавьте в файл `.htaccess` в корне сайта

2) (Если у вас есть доступ к конфигам) Включение вывода всех ошибок и предупреждений в файле `php.ini`:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
```

3) Включение вывода всех ошибок и предупреждений в коде PHP-скриптов.

Включить вывод уведомлений и предупреждений можно, добавив в начало нужного .php файла следующие строки:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

Этот способ может охватить не все типы ошибок, потому не рекомендую.

Comment: создал в корне сайта файл error.htaccess  и в него засунул

Comment: php_value display_errors 1
php_value display_startup_errors 1
php_value error_reporting E_ALL

Comment: без открытия и закрытия php

Comment: так будет верно?

Comment: @Дмитрий Нет, файл должен называться `.htaccess`. Т.е. имя файла **начинается с точки**

Comment: @Дмитрий **Не благодарите автора ответа в комментариях.**

Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers